# How to force Bootstrap calendar to focus and open under the <i> tag when click on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, focus

I have a Bootstrap calendar. It opens when I click on the calendar icon but it does not open when I click on the input. I want to make the calendar open under the calendar icon not under the input element when click on input.

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="11/03/2017" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
<input class="span2" id="dp2" size="16" type="text" value="11/03/2017">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dp3').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                })
                    .on('changeDate', function(){
                        $('#dp3').datepicker('hide');
                    });

        $('#dp2').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#dp3').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                })
                    .on('changeDate', function(){

                        $('#dp3').datepicker('hide');
                    });
    });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple questions are not answered here. Instead of clicking to the vote down button it would be useful to provide a working example link. Anyway took more then half an hour but made it to work it was very simple. didn't think to use  `$('#dp3').datepicker('show');`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#dp3").datepicker();

        $('#dp2').click(function () {
            $('#dp3').datepicker('show');
        });
  });
```